# unique constraint violated even if there is no primary key oracle

Tags: oracle

Getting error ora-00001 on oracle database while trying to insert new record.
There is no primary key in table
Error description :
unique constraint violated  even if there is no primary key oracle.

Comment: Check if there is unique constraint defined on this table. You will receive this message also if you are violating some unique constraint.

Comment: I am not sure how to check unique constraint, in constraints I dont get any. There are indexes on some columns, but no constraints .

Comment: What constraints do you have on the table? `SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'U';`

Comment: You will also receive this error if there is unique index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an unique index which was causing this error